# rank() with repeating value in partition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to use rank function in sql server with repeating value in the "partition by" clause, but I can't get exactly what I need. 
This is my query :

```
select jobID, runStatus, 
rank() over (partition by runStatus order by jobID ) as rank
from table
```

and I get:

```
jobID  runStatus  rank
10     s          9
9      s          8
8      s          7
7      s          6
6      s          5
5      s          4
4      f          1
3      s          3
2      s          2
1      s          1
```

but what I really need is:

```
jobID  runStatus  rank desire
10     s          6
9      s          5
8      s          4
7      s          3
6      s          2
5      s          1
4      f          1
3      s          3
2      s          2
1      s          1
```

meaning that the rank will be initialized every change in runStatus column.

Can you pls help me with that?

tnx,
E

Answer (score 5):

You need to define the groups.  This is called a "gap-and-islands" problem.  And one solution is the difference of row numbers.  For your data, this looks like:

```
select jobID, runStatus, 
       row_number() over (partition by runStatus, seqnum - seqnum_rs
                          order by jobID
                         ) as rank
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by jobId) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by runStatus order by jobId) as seqnum_rs
      from t
     ) t;
```

Your data has no duplicates, so `row_number()` appears to do what you want.  Regardless of the `rank()` or `row_number()` in the outer query, you want `row_number()` in the inner query.

To understand how this works, I recommend that you run in subquery.  Stare at the results until you "get" why the difference defines the groups you want.

Comment: WOW !  It is super helpful !   thank you very much @Gordon Linoff